# notification icon setting after click-once deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, system-tray, notifyicon

I have a click-once deployed app that uses a notification icon created using the [Hardcodet WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon). When I deploy it and initially install it, Windows hides the icon by default (as it should). So I change the setting for the app to "always show icon and notifications". But every time I update to a new version, Windows thinks it's a new app and hides it again. Is there any way to get Windows to retain the visibility setting for my notify icon after an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to get ClickOnce to handle this. This comes up periodically in the MSDN ClickOnce forum, and since Bing is my friend, I can provide you with [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/c33ab558-7fd5-4330-a985-9702358472d0) to one of the articles that has some ideas about it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that's the answer you are looking for, but I do not think it's possible "out of the box". Every clickonce version is a different app from Windows perspective. I had the same issue with Windows Firewall - firewall rules are not be preserved when update is installed. I guess the only solution for you would be to find a way to manually add your application to that list.